# Optimize MySQL trigger performance

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I have following table structure. Added two triggers, but as the triggers work with string values and they search for string the database performance might degrade in future when every table will get huge. I have no strong experience with indexes, and don't know which fields to index to make trigger's search operation fast even with millions of rows.

What do you suggest?

```
   CREATE TABLE `ofRoster` (
      `rosterID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
      `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
      `jid` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
      `sub` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
      `ask` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
      `recv` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
      `nick` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`rosterID`),
      KEY `ofRoster_unameid_idx` (`username`),
      KEY `ofRoster_jid_idx` (`jid`(255))
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


    CREATE TABLE `ofUser` (
      `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
      `plainPassword` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
      `encryptedPassword` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `creationDate` char(15) NOT NULL,
      `modificationDate` char(15) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`username`),
      KEY `ofUser_cDate_idx` (`creationDate`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


    delimiter ;;
    CREATE TRIGGER `UpdateNickOnInsert` BEFORE INSERT ON `ofRoster` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.nick=(SELECT name FROM ofUser where username=NEW.username);
    END
     ;;
    delimiter ;

    delimiter ;;
    CREATE TRIGGER `UpdateRosterNicksOnUpdate` AFTER UPDATE ON `ofUser` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.name <> OLD.name 
    THEN  
      UPDATE ofRoster r SET r.nick=NEW.name WHERE r.username=OLD.username;
    END IF;
    END
     ;;
    delimiter ;
```

Comment: For the second case, you are probably better off using cascading foreign key constraints; but why are you storing that string data redundantly? A simple user_id would be much more efficient.

Comment: @Uueerdo it's ready to go software database. Openfire servers. Not my fault.

Comment: Given your current indexes, and the queries in your triggers, I don't see much that can really be done to improve things; the fields used in the WHERE's already have appropriate indexes.

Comment: Why are you using triggers to update these fields?  Just use a `join` when you need the information.  Don't store duplicate information.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's ready to go software database. Openfire servers. Database design is not my fault.